# How to insert an hyperlink in a PDF in a Linux shell?

Tags: linux, pdf, hyperlink

It doesn't even have to be text. It would be enough just with a rectangle. I need something like this:

```
insert_hyperlink -file my_pdf -page 3 -href "superuser.com" -rect 100x100+600+0
```

I've seen posts about inserting text or watermarks but nothing about hyperlinks. I've also been redirected to tools like pdftk but I can't find the way to do this. Other sites solve it with Adobe and online tools, but I need something free that works on a Linux shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently found this python library that could do the trick: PyPDF2.

[Here](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/adding-pdf-annotations.html?highlight=link#link)'s the section in the documentation about adding link annotations.